# How do I set up a wireless router as a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have two Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH routers.  They are both running DD-WRT v24SP2-EU-US (08/19/10) std - build 14998 firmware.

I would like to set them up so that one is a wireless repeater of the other.  I would like to run WPA2 Personal Mixed (TKIP+AES) encryption on them.  I'd prefer them to be on the same subnet.  Is this possible?  How do I configure this?  I have tried following the directions at the DD-WRT site, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read [this](http://cdn.cloudfiles.mosso.com/c85091/WZR-HP-G300NH_dd-wrt_User_Manual.pdf), and came accross the answer on page **8**:

> WDS Station is the client in a WDS-AP <-> WDS 
>   station bridge. This is a special wireless 
>   networking mode that offers better 
>   flexibility and security than the classical 
>   MAC address based WDS.

Would a [WDS network](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WDS_Linked_router_network) fit your requirements?